# Limit PhotosPicker selectable items to only Albums (SwiftUI)

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, photosui, photospicker

Is there any way to use the PhotosUI PhotosPicker api in SwiftUI, but limit the user to picking only a single album, not individual photos or even multiple individual photos? The .photosPickerDisabledCapabilities modifier does not contain an option for this, so is my only option to use the UIKit api inside a UIViewControllerRepresentable?

Comment: You can give it a `PHPickerFilter`. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I think it would be that, but there isn't a filter for 'Albums'. I want to allow a user to pick an album, and only an album, to use for a photo frame feature. Thanks.

Comment: How would you do this in UIKit then? As far as I can see, `PhotosPicker` has almost the same capabilities as `PHPickerViewController`.

Comment: Only with a custom view, and it has to be done with the UIKit API.

Answer (score 1):

Yes your best option in this case would indeed be to use the UIKit API inside a UIViewControllerRepresentable.

Comment: Thanks. I hope they eventually add this capability to PhotosPicker.